# AuthorizeAttribute doesn't work when refresh the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have some problem with authorization:

The `AuthorizeWebForm` codes work when loading the page, I am not in the admin group so I don't have the access, which is great. But when I refresh the page, I have access to the page, and the code `AuthorizeWebFormAttribute` doesn't run when refresh. Any solution to this?

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthorizeWebFormAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public AuthorizeWebFormAttribute(string Roles = null)
    {
        IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (Roles == null)
                return;

            if (user.IsInRole("admin"))
                return;

            string[] roleArray = Roles.Split(',');
            foreach (var role in roleArray)
            {
                if (user.IsInRole(role))
                    return;
            }
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Server.TransferRequest("~/Unauthorized", false);
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace Crew
{
    [AuthorizeWebForm("admin")]
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["EmpNo_User"].ToString()))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx?CustError=This page expired. Please close the broswer and open again.");
        }
        Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
    }
```

}

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure that this is the way to write an authozization attribute? You are missing some overrides there for things you tried to handle in the constructor. Take a look here: https://blog.georgekosmidis.net/2014/05/17/mvc-custom-authorizeattribute-for-custom-authentication/

Comment: That's just partial code. It works fine, but when refreshing, these codes will not be executed....

Comment: It can't work fine. The attribute is instantiated when the construct (method in your case) it is attached to is first touched. Thus the `HttpContext.Current.User` is evaluated only once in the lifetime of the application instance (assuming you are hosting your app under IIS). As long as the request is reaching the same application instance, this code is not called again. On the other hand, why don't you use the normal way of performing authorization? You should insert a handler into the ASP:NET MVC pipeline rather than attaching such attributes on legacy event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel here. There's a perfectly good `AuthorizeAttribute` class you can use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Also take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs for role-based security in general.